# Mongo userAdminAnyDatabase can't create users in other database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having a user `root` in `admin` DB, also have authentication enabled.

After authentication on `admin` DB as `root` user, if i enter `show users`

I can see the below the output

```
{
        "_id" : "admin.root",
        "user" : "root",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
```

I have another database `my_test_db`

I was trying to create a new user in `my_test_db` using the below command

```
use my_test_db

db.createUser({
... user: 'tesuser',
... pwd: 'passwor123',
... roles: [{role: 'read', db: 'my_test_db'}]
... })
```

But i got unauthorised error.

If i am `userAdminAnyDatabase` should i have `createUser` access to all the DBs ?

Or i am doing something wrong ?

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing is correct. To confirm I tried the same and its working fine for me.

Possible errors:

1. You may be not logged in as user `root`
2. What version of MongoDB you are using?

Other than this I don't see any other possibilities.

> If possible please post your error as well.